# printing keywords from a list

Tags: python-3.x

can anyone tell me how to print the word in the from the lists once the program has found them?

```
all_text = input("Please enter some text").lower().split()
keyword_list = ["motorcycle","bike","cycle","dirtbike"]
second_list = ["screen","cracked","scratched"]

if any(word in keyword_list for word in all_text):
    print("Keyword found")
    if any(word in second_list for word in all_text):
        print("Keyword found")
elif any(word in second_list for word in all_text):
    print("keyword found")
```

Comment: it is hard to print data if you haven't saved it. Why not create an initially empty list `found_words` which you append to when you find a word? Also -- this sort of thing is much better done using `sets` rather than `lists`, but you might not have studied sets yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right you want the same thing if it is in ether `list`.  If you want to split it you can just do an `elif`.

```
all_text = input("Please enter some text").lower().split()

keyword_list = ["motorcycle","bike","cycle","dirtbike"]

second_list = ["screen","cracked","scratched"]


for word in all_text:
  if word in second_list or word in keyword_list:
    print("Keyword found " + word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using plain `for` loop would be much easier than `any` for this task

```
all_text = input("Please enter some text").lower().split()
keyword_list = ["motorcycle","bike","cycle","dirtbike"]
second_list = ["screen","cracked","scratched"]

for word in all_text: 
    # note that you can't use word in keyword_list 
    # because it'll also match bike with dirtbike etc.
    for keyword in keyword_list:
        if word == keyword:
            print("Word " + word + "in first keyword list")
            break

    for keyword in second_list:
        if word == keyword:
            print("Word " + word + "in second keyword list")
            break
```

Comment: thanks lafexlos you have given me the solution i needed to begin my gcse second programming task :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a handle on the use of `in` in Python but for future readers I'll note that Python's `in` can be used to implicitly search a list and avoid a second `for` loop when comparing elements in two lists.

```
all_text = input("Please enter some text").lower().split()
keyword_list = ["motorcycle","bike","cycle","dirtbike"]
second_list = ["screen","cracked","scratched"]

for word in all_text: 
    if word in keyword_list:
        print("Word '{}' found in keyword_list".format(word))
    elif word in second_list:
        print("Word '{}' found in second_list".format(word))
```

*"can anyone tell me how to print the word (...)"*?

Python supports at least three ways of dynamically creating strings...

A `printf`-ish style that'll probably look familiar to C coders:

```
>>> "Inserted word: %s" % "Hi!"
'Inserted word: Hi!'
>>>
```

Using `str`s `format` method:

```
>>> "Inserted word: {}".format("Hi!")
'Inserted word: Hi!'
>>>
```

(Ab)using the `+` operator:

```
>>> "Inserted word: " + "Hi!"
'Inserted word: Hi!'
>>>
```